# Crear columna basada en un diccionario pandas

Tags: lista, pandas, diccionarios

Tengo una serie de textos, que tienen nombres definidos que tengo que buscar.  Aquí un ejemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = {'Descripcion':['RB Energía', 'Red Bull bebida', 'Rufo Bueno', 'Rosca Batacona']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

Utilizando un diccionario para crear una columna:

```
d = {'RB': 'Red Bull, 'Red Bull': 'Red Bull'}
df=df.replace (d)
```

Me crea la columna, pero se obtiene el mismo resultado que la columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado también con el siguiente código (siendo este el que realmente me interesa) en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590180/looking-for-words-in-string-that-matches-the-values-in-a-dictionary-then-return

```
marca = {'red bull': ('red bull'), 'rb': ('red bull')}

def marca1(x):
    for key, values in marca.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in x.lower():
                return key
    else:
        return np.nan

df4['Marca2'] = df4['Descripcion'].apply(marca1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me elimina aquellos que no cumplen con lo especificado.  ¿Cuál puede ser el error?

Lo que se busca con el diccionario es que si encuentra la palabra definida cree la columna marca, para claridad:

RB Energía el resultado debe ser Red Bull
Red Bull bebida el resultado debe ser Red Bull
Rufo Bueno nan (vacía, no cumple)
Rosca Batacona (vacía, no cumple)

Los últimos dos cumplen con que sean RB (en diferentes posiciones) y no debe ser identificado como Red Bull.

Gracias.

Comment: Buen dia, no me queda del todo claro lo que desea hacer ¿Podria editar su pregunta y anexar el resultado que espera?

Comment: Gracias, he editado la pregunta, espero esté claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si únicamente quieres reemplazar `N` cantidad de `strings` por "Red Bull", lo puedes hacer combinando `apply` con `any` y un generador, de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Descripcion':['RB Energía', 'Red Bull bebida', 'Rufo Bueno', 'Rosca Batacona']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Marca'] = df['Descripcion'].apply(lambda x: 'Red Bull' if any(e in x for e in ['RB', 'Red Bull']) else np.nan)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Descripcion     Marca
0   RB Energía      Red Bull
1   Red Bull bebida Red Bull
2   Rufo Bueno      NaN
3   Rosca Batacona  NaN
```

Pero la desventaja es que si quisieras en un futuro reemplazar diferentes marcas entonces tendrías que repetir el mismo código una y otra vez las veces que sea necesario.

Ahora, en la función `marca1` hay unos errores de concepto

1. No es necesario utilizar el segundo ciclo `for` para recorrer los valores.
2. No es necesario utilizar `else` en el `for` ya que si no se encuentra la llave en el `string` puede directamente hacer `return`

Aplicando los comentarios anteriores podemos crear la función `reemplazar` (Agregué la llave "Rosca" para mostrar que se pueden agregar tantas llaves como se desee)

```
d = {'RB': 'Red Bull', 'Red Bull': 'Red Bull', 'Rosca': 'Prueba'}

def reemplazar(x):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in x:
            return v
    return np.nan
```

**Nota:** Puedes modificar la función utilizando `lower()` como lo intentaste hacer en tu pregunta para crear menos llaves en el diccionario `d`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Descripcion':['RB Energía', 'Red Bull bebida', 'Rufo Bueno', 'Rosca Batacona']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

d = {'RB': 'Red Bull', 'Red Bull': 'Red Bull', 'Rosca': 'Prueba'}

def reemplazar(x):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in x:
            return v
    return np.nan

df['Marca'] = df['Descripcion'].apply(reemplazar)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Descripcion     Marca
0   RB Energía      Red Bull
1   Red Bull bebida Red Bull
2   Rufo Bueno      NaN
3   Rosca Batacona  Prueba
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.   Funcionó.  Otra consulta, por ejemplo, en el diccionario definido, si las marcas no van en orden, existe la posibilidad de que encuentre palabras que son iguales.   Este ejemplo:   d : {'ADES'}  y en el texto aparece un string que dice "MANZANAS EN UNIDADES" y en otro dice "BEBIDA DE SOYA ADES", ¿cómo le pongo un limitador inicial y final para que sólo identifique la palabra buscadas del diccionario?  Gracias.

Comment: Buen día @user17743486, si la respuesta te fue útil por favor acéptala, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: En el ejemplo que pusiste podrías llamar la clave ` ADES` (Con un espacio al inicio).