# Crear columna a partir de una búsqueda en diccionario python

Tags: python, bucle-for, diccionarios

Tengo una columna que he llamado nombres y he creado un diccionario con notas. Necesito crear una nueva columna con los valores del diccionario después de que busque las claves de ese diccionario en la columna nombres. Lo necesito hacer con un bucle `for` y quería además intentar hacerlo con una `comprehension list` pero no lo consigo. He buscado en esta página y he encontrado cómo hacer con una función y después aplicando apply en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/545447/crear-columna-basada-en-un-diccionario-pandas) pero quisiera aprender a hacerlo con un bucle for.

```
nombres = ['Juan', 'Roberto', 'Eva', 'Luis', 'Ana']
notas = {'Ana':3, 'Roberto':1, 'Eva':0, 'Luis':5, 'Juan':2}
```

He probado a hacer lo siguiente:

```
nueva_lista = [value for i in notas.keys() for value in nombres[i]]
print(nueva_lista)
```

Y sin `comprehension list`:

```
for keys,values in notas():
    if keys in nombres:
        print(notas.values)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: En Pandas, el bucle for debe de ser el ultimo recurso. Pues dicho modulo ofrece formas mas rapidas como apply. Por que la necesidad de que sea con un bucle for?

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema y un ejemplo de lo que quisieras obtener como resultado.

Comment: Creo que existe un error de conceptos acá, tu mencionas **Columna** pero en tu código solo veo listas y diccionarios. En teoría lo que deseas es crear una lista en base  los valores de un diccionario que coincidan con los valores de otra lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando referencia de los datos proporcionados:

```python
nombres = ['Juan', 'Roberto', 'Eva', 'Luis', 'Ana']
notas = {'Ana':3, 'Roberto':1, 'Eva':0, 'Luis':5, 'Juan':2}
```

Utilizando `for`:

```pythom
new_list = []
for nombre in nombres:
    if nombre in notas:
        new_list.append(notas[nombre])
```

Utilizando comprenhension list

```
new_list = [notas[nombre] for nombre in nombres if nombre in notas]
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla pero poco eficiente de hacerlo seria algo así:

```
lista=[]
for p in notas:
    if p in nombres:
        lista+=[notas[p]]
    
print(lista)
```

- p son las palabras claves del diccionario notas.
- notas[p] la definición o valor asociado a la clave p.
- lista+=[notas[p]] va concatenado o anexando los valores a la lista

Output:
[3, 1, 0, 5, 2]

Otra forma mas complicada de leer pero mas efectiva:

```
lista=[]
for key,valor in notas.items():
    if key in nombres:
        lista.append(valor)
    
print(lista)
```

Y la mas compacta Y EFECTIVA:

```
lista = [value for key,value in notas.items() if key in nombres]
```

Comment: La primera es menos efectiva Porque crea 2 listas nuevas en cada iteracion y hace una asignacion. En cambio la forma "complicada" solamente modifica la lista original.

Comment: Cierto, además la primera tiene que hacer una búsqueda en el diccionario para encontrar el valor